# Global NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to create a NSOperationQueue and add a NSOperation to it. Later I wan't to check if the queue is running and maybe abort it. All of that is supposed to be called from within different functions. What's the best approach to do this? I would be glad for a code example. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question but Grand Central Dispatch offer global queues out of the box.

Comment: This could be the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I managed to create and add a queue but I can't figure out how to cancel a task in the queue.

Comment: That's one of the caveats of GCD. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449469/can-you-use-cancel-iscancelled-with-gcd-dispatch-async

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create an operation queue that's managed by a singleton.

First, create your singleton class. It will provide access to the `NSOperationQueue`. Let's call the singleton `MyGlobalQueueManager`.

It will have an `ivar` called `myGlobalQueue`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue* myGlobalQueue;
```

In the `.m` file of `MyGlobalQueueManager`, create a fairly standard `init` method that will set up the operation queue:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        myGlobalOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, the method that provides itself as a singleton. Again, this is pretty standard stuff:

```
 + (MyGlobalQueueManager *)sharedInstance
{
    static MyGlobalQueueManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t isDispatched;

    dispatch_once(&isDispatched, ^
                  {
                      sharedInstance = [[MyGlobalQueueManager alloc] init];
                  });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Let's access that queue from wherever you want to use it:

```
MyGlobalQueueManager* myGlobalQueueManager = [MyGlobalQueueManager sharedInstance];
NSOperationQueue *myGlobalQueue = myGlobalQueueManager.myGlobalOperationQueue;
```

You can then add operations to that queue as you fancy.

How to know if anythings queued?

```
NSUInteger count = [myGlobalQueue operationCount];
```

How to abort? Cancel everything as follows:

```
[myGlobalQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Cancelling of course depends on the operations. If you're writing custom `NSOperation` classes, you'll need to handle that yourself.

I find `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` to be fairly easy to use and quite straightforward.

A great document to read for all this is the Concurrency Programming Guide. Specifically, have a look at [Operation Queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html)

Comment: Hey @Max MacLeod if I have two uicontrollers and in first in viewWillDisappear call function cancelAllOperations on Singleton's Queue will it make effect on NSOpearation that I start in 2nd viewcontroller's viewdidload where first is pushing 2nd by navigation controller?

Comment: In that case I would have a queue in each view controller. Otherwise it becomes more complicated. Have a look at the MVCNetworking sample project provided by Apple. It demonstrates a network manager singleton that operates three or four different queues.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do it is to make a "globally visible" function.  AKA, declare it in a public header:

```
extern NSOperationQueue * SharedQueue();
```

and define it within your compilation "unit" - but ***outside*** any `@implementation`.

```
NSOperationQueue *SharedOperationQueue()
{
  static NSOperationQueue * _SharedQueue = nil;
  return _SharedQueue ?: ^{ _SharedQueue = NSOperationQueue.new;
                            _SharedQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount;
                     return _SharedQueue;
  }();
}
```

As a little bonus..  `#define` it with an "alias".. and you can REALLy abuse it!

```
#define MY_SOQ SharedOperationQueue()

[MY_SOQ addOperationWithBlock:^{ /* GO CRAZY */ }];
```