# Delete / stop dispatch_async iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I created a dispatch_async to download data to a web services.

I created an alert with a button from the possibilida to cancel / block the download.

My question is:

How can I delete / stop my dispatch_async?

This is my dispatch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no direct way to do that with `GCD`, but you could use a `NSOperationQueue` and call the method `cancelAllOperations`. `NSOperationQueue` uses `GCD` internally anyway.

Comment: I was reading this in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546385/kill-items-in-a-dispatch-async-queue-in-ios

But I did not understand, you can give an example? Thank You

Comment: It's a bit more overhead than just that dispatch call right now. You can check this tutorial for starters: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider accepting it so others know which solution worked for you.