# iphone-dev: Abort a dispatch_queue

Tags: objective-c, ios, queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dispatch queues: How to tell if they're running and how to stop them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550658/dispatch-queues-how-to-tell-if-theyre-running-and-how-to-stop-them)

Is there a way to stop / abort a specific queue ? If my created queue is:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
```

Can i then somehow abort this queue on for example a buttonclick? so basically i want this:

```
dispatch_queue_abort("com.example.MyQueue");
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no api to cancel a queue.. you can refer to this answer for more details.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551056/919545