# Stopping a query to firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

        inSearchMode = false

    } else {

        if allInterestsArray.contains(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) {

          ref.child(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString).child("users")

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

                print("this should be running")
                print(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)

                let handle = roomsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                    print(snapshot.value)

                    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                        for snap in snapshots {

                            print(snap)
                        }

                    }

                })
            }
        }
        else {
            print("doesn't exist")
        }


    }
}
```

I'm running a query to my firebase database when my searchBar.text is equal to something in my allInterestsArray. This is being checked for on keystroke, and I'm using dispatch_after to prevent a query being sent until the user is probably done typing.

What is happening is if I have the item in my array of "Dog" and the user gets to "dog" and then types in an "s" which makes it "dogs"..the query is still being sent off for dog and then again for dogs, so I need to cancel the query up at the top of my textDidChange func I think so on each keystroke it's being canceled, and only after a second of no typing is the query being sent off.

I was thinking of using removeHandle but I don't think that's what that's meant to be used for?

Example:

If my array = ["dog","dogs","doggies"]

The user types quickly enough so there's not a full 1 second between any two letters (one second because of the dispatch_after time I set) and they type in "dogs".. the query for dog should not have gone off, only for "dogs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be solved using a global variable called "keepSearching" as below :

EDIT : I've now also used NSTimer to give a one-second gap for "keepSearching" to be false.

```
var keepSearching: Bool = true
var timer = NSTimer()
func timerAction() {
    keepSearching = false
}
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
    inSearchMode = false

} 
else if(keepSearching) {

    if allInterestsArray.contains(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) {


      // just in case user keeps on typing, invalidate the previous timer, before it happens.
      timer.invalidate()

      // schedule a new timer everytime.
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

      ref.child(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString).child("users")

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            print("this should be running")
            print(searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)

            let handle = roomsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                print(snapshot.value)

                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshots {

                        print(snap)
                    }

                }

            })
        }
    }
    else {
        print("doesn't exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this read "once a match has been found in allInterestsArrays, fireoff a search but don't fire off searches anymore?"

So in this example if my allInterestArrays = ["dog","dogs","doggies"]

and my user was wanting to get to doggies, wouldn't this code get to "dog" and then stop because keepSearching is set to false?

I'm needing for the search to only get fired off if the searchbar's text matches dog/dogs/doggies AND it's been a second since they've last typed.

So if the user types "dogs" quickly, a query for "dog" should not have gone off at all.

Comment: @Hibernia : Yes. You're correct. I've now added the NSTimer to include a delay of 1 second before the variable 'keepSearching' is set to false. Also, if the user keeps on typing, previous timer is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property that gets incremented every time a `dispatch_after` block is submitted, and check if that value corresponds to the current one. This way you'll be able to tell if you should kick-off or not the request. Here how your controller class might look like (included only the relevant pieces to this question):

```
class MyController: <base class, protocols> {

    var requestsCounter = 0

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // mark that a new request is made
        self.requestsCounter++

        // save the number in a local var to be used when the block
        // actually executes
        let currentCounter = self.requestsCounter

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            inSearchMode = false
        } else {
            dispatch_after(...) { () -> Void in

            // if another dispatch_after was submitted, then the value of the 
            // currentCounter local variable won't match the property value,
            // so we should no longer proceeed
            guard currentCounter == self.requestsCounter  else { return }

            // ... the original code here
        }
    }
```

How does it work:

- the first time the delegate method is called, it increments the `requestsCounter` property, so now it has a value of 1
- this value (1) gets saved into the local variable `currentCounter`, whos value is captured by the `dispatch_after` closure.
- if the delegate method is called before `dispatch_after` executes the closure, then the `requestsCounter` will be incremented to 2, and a new `currentCounter` variable, with that value, will be created and captured by the 2nd `dispatch_after` closure
- now when the first `dispatch_after` closure executes, it captured `currentCounter` value will hold 1, but `self.requestsCounter` will be 2, thus the closure will return without doing actual work
- the same logic applies for subsequent requests, the `searchBar: textDidChange:` delegate method will increment every time the `requestsCounter` property, which in turn will invalidate previously scheduled closures, as each captures the old values of the `requestsCounter` property.

Comment: I did some looking around and I saw this very similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232655/how-to-implement-work-queue-in-ios-where-only-newest-request-is-handled/13233208#13233208 and he does basically exactly what you've done here. I just am havin a hard time understanding how this works.

I think I'm confused where things actually go. So I'm globally defining requests counter. Then in my ifArraycontains check I up the requestsCounter? But then I'm not sure where to put the currentCounter.

Sorry this is a bit beyond me lol.

Comment: Basically just trying to accomplish exactly what instagram does where you search and it's not until you've stopped typing for a tiny bit that you get the query sent out so that if you want "bobby" and there's a "bob" your'e not sending a query off at bob.

Comment: additionally, and sorry for spamming the comments here...Would there be an issue with just when the user starts typing setting a timer...and testing when that timer hits like 1.5 seconds then running the query? and each time a letter is changed it sets the timer back down to 0